# jquery - selector won't log element

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

This is my code:

```js
const request = require("request-promise");
const Cheerio = require("cheerio");

async function scrapeTitles() {
  const result = await request.get(
    "https://opensea.io/assets/zunks?search[resultModel]=ASSETS&search[sortAscending]=false&search[sortBy]=LAST_SALE_DATE&search[stringTraits][0][name]=Hats%2FHair&search[stringTraits][0][values][0]=Straight%20Hair"
  );
  const $ = await Cheerio.load(result);

  const zunks = $(
    " div.Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0.kOkNk > div.AssetCardFooter--name"
  )
    .map((i, element) => {
      return $(element).text();
    })
    .get();
  console.log(zunks);
}
scrapeTitles();
```

I can't add the full console log because it is so long so I will just add a little bit:

```
writable: true,
destroyed: false,
_last: true,
chunkedEncoding: false,
shouldKeepAlive: false,
_defaultKeepAlive: true,
useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
sendDate: false,
_removedConnection: false,
_removedContLen: false,
_removedTE: false,
_contentLength: 0,
_hasBody: true,
_trailer: '',
finished: true,
_headerSent: true,
_closed: false,
socket: <ref *1> TLSSocket {
  _tlsOptions: {
    allowHalfOpen: undefined,
    pipe: false,
    secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {} },
    isServer: false,
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    session: undefined,
    ALPNProtocols: undefined,
    requestOCSP: undefined,
    enableTrace: undefined,
    pskCallback: undefined,
    highWaterMark: undefined,
    onread: undefined,
    signal: undefined
  },
  _secureEstablished: true,
  _securePending: false,
  _newSessionPending: false,
  _controlReleased: true,
  secureConnecting: false,
  _SNICallback: null,
  servername: 'opensea.io',
  alpnProtocol: false,
  authorized: true,
  authorizationError: null,
  encrypted: true,
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    close: [
      [Function: onSocketCloseDestroySSL],
      [Function],
      [Function: onClose],
      [Function: socketCloseListener]
    ],
    end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
    newListener: [Function: keylogNewListener],
    secure: [Function: onConnectSecure],
    session: [Function (anonymous)],
    free: [Function: onFree],
    timeout: [Function: onTimeout],
    agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
    error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
    finish: [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
      listener: [Function: destroy]
    }
  },
  _eventsCount: 10,
  connecting: false,
  _hadError: false,
  _parent: null,
  _host: 'opensea.io',
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: true,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: true,
    constructed: true,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: true,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: false,
    autoDestroy: true,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
  },
```

To be honest, I have no idea what this means or where to go from here so if you could point me in the right direction would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Not sure if there's any such thing as Array.prototype.get

Comment: @UtkarshDixit that's not array.get - more specifically, it's not js map - it's jquery map get - see: https://api.jquery.com/map/  *As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array.*  (well, I'm guessing it is from the tag [tag:jquery] - but not so sure with `const $ = await Cheerio.load(result);` - so `$` may not be pure `jquery`

Comment: Ah, jQuery once used to be my fav library and now i don't even remember its API

Comment: Instead of `.get()` try `.toArray()` as shown in the docs https://cheerio.js.org/classes/Cheerio.html#map

Comment: That's not the output you would get from this code. Maybe upgrade cheerio. I'm not sure about the request part because nobody uses that anymore.

Comment: Code looks OK to me. No need to `await` on `cheerio.load()` but that's cosmetic. Page is now 404 so voting to close as not reproducible.